# My ADT Plugin is updated , but eclipse doesn't recognize it

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have updated the Android SDK and I have installed API 17. I also updated the ADT Plugin to 21.1.0. However I'm facing a problem : when I open eclipse a message keeps appearing :

> The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or
>   above. Current version is : 21.0.1.v201....(& another numbers..).
>   Please update ADT to the latest version.

I click `Check for updates` --> Then appears a message :`No updates found` 
And another message appear: `No repository found at jar:file:/C:(...)/ADT-21.1.0.zip!/`.

I cannot start the avd because all the applications have errors.

I also tried to install it manually by downloading the zip file `ADT-21.1.0 -> Help -> Install New Software... -> Add -> Archive`....(this is the way that I updated the Plugin in the first place) , but it says that everything is updated !!
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know the reason but the following helped me in the same situation.

- Go to Help -> Install New Software
- Use (add if not exist) Android Developer Tools Update Site (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
- **Uncheck** "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option

Comment: My ADT Plugin is already updated - VER : 21.1.0 but eclipse doesn't recognize that

Comment: Unchecking "Contact all" fixed this issue for me. It failed to install otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before - Solved it by using an updated Eclipse with a new installation of the ADT (installing it like Serkan has suggested, instead of using the Marketplace).

Comment: I tried that , the Developer Tools is already UPDATED to ver 21.1.0! The problem is that eclipse doesn't "understand" that

Comment: I'll try to download  the latest Eclipse and see what happens.Thanks

Comment: I download a newer ver of eclipse and it works...but i still have the same problem with the old ver

Answer (score 0):

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
The Site is https not http. So make the necessary change, it should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it is looking for an update repository which does not exist on your c drive.
It got stuck on c because you loaded a zip.
fix by going to help software install then click available software sites and remove your local drives.